# Find the number a that makes $f(x)$ continuous everywhere?

Tags: limits, continuity

$$
  f(x)=
  \begin{cases}
     ax^2-3 & \text{if $x\leqslant 2$,} \\
     2ax+3  & \text{if $x > 2$.}
  \end{cases}
$$
$$\lim_{x\to 2^-} ax^2-3 = 4a-3$$
$$\lim_{x\to 2^+} 2ax+3 =4a+3$$
$$
\begin{align*}
  \text{limit RHS} &= \text{limit LHS} \\
   4a+3 &= 4a-3 \\
      0 &=6
\end{align*}
$$ 
What mistake have i done here?

Comment: If you just need $f$ to be continuous, why are you differentiating?

Comment: I haven't differentiated any function, f(x)=ax^2-3 at x<=2 and =2ax-3 in the interval x>2.

Comment: It seem all correct to me.

Comment: If a=0, then f(2)=-3 is defined and the limit as x approaches from the left handside of 2 is equal to -3 and the limit as x approaches to 2 from the right hand side therefore the limit as x approaches to 2 does not exist making f(x) discontinuous.

Comment: You have no mistake.There is no number $a$ .

Comment: Function is discontinuous,yes?

Answer (score 3):

You have done no mistake. On computing,$$LHL=RHL=f(2)$$ $$\implies0=6$$ which is impossible and hence there is no such $'a'$ exists or $$a\in\phi$$